# List of uneven data to dataframe

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, dataframe

I have list of list with uneven data. Something like this

```
 val list = List(List("1","2","3"), List("3","4","null","6"), List("1","4","5","6","7"))
```

can someone tell me how can i convert this data to dataframe and latter write this data to csv.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried following:

```
 import sqlContext.implicits._ 
 val df = list.toDS.toDF 
 df.show()
```

This gave me the required dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
 scala> val df = list.toDF
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: array<string>]

scala> df.show
+---------------+
|          value|
+---------------+
|      [1, 2, 3]|
|[3, 4, null, 6]|
|[1, 4, 5, 6, 7]|
+---------------+

scala> df.toJSON.write.csv(path)
```

It won't let u write in CSV format. As it is an unsupported operation for an array of String datatype. You can convert it to JSON and then save it as in CSV file.

```
scala> df.toJSON.write.csv(path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. However the type of val list is List[List[String]]. I am unable to convert it to toDF. The error i am getting is value `toDF is not a member of 
  List[List[String]]`

Comment: Show your exact data because from above information it is list of list of int.

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it will help.